# how to subset data frame if all the conditions are met?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

i have two message ids say 197, 198 . I want to subset the data frame  for those users who have got the messages from these ids. I only want those rows which contains both these message ids.

The data frame is `m`

I have used the code

```
a = c(197,198)
n = subset(m$userid,m$mid %in% a)
```

I also tried

```
n = m[m$mid == 197 & m$mid == 198]
```

both of these codes are creating OR output whereas I want AND output.

here is the sample dataframe:

```
mid userid opened

197 1022    Y
197 1036    N
197 1100    Y
198 1000    Y
198 1022    N
198 1036    Y
```

I want output as records containing userid for both mid 197 &198

```
mid userid opened
197 1022    Y
197 1036    N
198 1022    N
198 1036    Y
```

Comment: If `m` is a data.frame you need a comma `m[m$mid == 197 | m$mid == 198, ]` or `subset(m, mid %in% 197:198))`  The logical statement of 'mid' having both  197 and 198 at the same row is not possible.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output for others to help you better

Comment: @Prajna can you help us with sample data for `m`

Comment: Please use `dput` and share part of `m`. It seems a separate different question and could stand on its own.

Comment: A possible solution using `sqldf` could be: `sqldf("SELECT * FROM m 
                WHERE userid in (SELECT userid FROM m WHERE mid == 197) AND
                userid in (SELECT userid FROM m WHERE mid == 198)")`

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(userid) %>%
  filter(all(c(197, 198) %in% mid))
` or in base R `df[ave(df$mid, df$userid, FUN = function(x) all(c(197, 198) %in% x)) == 1, ]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf` one solution could be achieved as:

```
# data
m <- read.table(text = "mid userid opened
197 1022    Y
197 1036    N
197 1100    Y
198 1000    Y
198 1022    N
198 1036    Y", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(sqldf)

result <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM m 
                WHERE userid in (SELECT userid FROM m WHERE mid == 197) AND
                userid in (SELECT userid FROM m WHERE mid == 198)")

result 

#     mid userid opened
#   1 197   1022      Y
#   2 197   1036      N
#   3 198   1022      N
#   4 198   1036      Y
```

Comment: Can also express using WITH clause: `sqldf("WITH userid197 AS (SELECT userid FROM m WHERE mid == 197),
       userid198 AS (SELECT userid FROM m WHERE mid == 198)
  SELECT * FROM m WHERE userid IN userid197 AND userid IN userid198")`

Comment: How can you scale this approach if there are more than 2 elements in `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Using duplicated :

```
m[duplicated(m$userid) | duplicated(m$userid,fromLast = T), ]

#   mid userid opened
# 1 197   1022      Y
# 2 197   1036      N
# 5 198   1022      N
# 6 198   1036      Y
```

With your real data you may need first : `m2 <- subset(m,mid %in% a)` to make sure you have only `mid` from `a` in your table before applying my solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here are two `data.table` approaches. Both are capable of handling `a` of arbitrary length, i.e., with more than just 2 selected `mid`.

#### Join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(m)[m[mid %in% a][, uniqueN(mid), by = .(userid)][V1 == uniqueN(a)],
         on = "userid"]
```

> ```
>    mid userid opened V1
> 1: 197   1022      Y  2
> 2: 198   1022      N  2
> 3: 197   1036      N  2
> 4: 198   1036      Y  2
> ```

The expression

```
m[mid %in% a][, uniqueN(mid), by = .(userid)][V1 == uniqueN(a)]
```

> ```
>    userid V1
> 1:   1022  2
> 2:   1036  2
> ```

filters `m`, then counts the number of unique `mid` by `userid` and returns those `userid` which have matches with all entries in `a`. (Instead of  `uniqueN(a)`, `length(a)` can be used but the former is safer).

#### Subsetting by row indices

There is an alternative approach which returns the row id's of `m` which are then used for subsetting:

```
m[mid %in% a][, .I[uniqueN(mid) == uniqueN(a)], by = .(userid)]
```

> ```
>    userid V1
> 1:   1022  1
> 2:   1022  5
> 3:   1036  2
> 4:   1036  6
> ```

```
m[m[mid %in% a][, .I[uniqueN(mid) == uniqueN(a)], by = .(userid)]$V1]
```

> ```
>    mid userid opened
> 1: 197   1022      Y
> 2: 198   1022      N
> 3: 197   1036      N
> 4: 198   1036      Y
> ```